# How to dynamically pass the property in Spring FTP Outboud channel context xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext, ftp-client

The FTPapplicationContext.xml has the configuration to create the beans for FTPchannel. here it takes the property values from the application.proprty. Now my question is how to dynamically set the property while on the run time.

**Context.xml:**

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${availableServerPort}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${userid}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter  id="ftpOutbound"
            channel="ftpChannel"
            remote-directory="/temp"
            session-factory="ftpClientFactory">
    <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice />
    </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

**application.prperties:**

```
userid=Administrator
password=password
availableServerPort=21
host=Testfar
```

**FTP code:**

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
          new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");

 MessageChannel ftpChannel = context.getBean("ftpChannel",MessageChannel.class);
  File file1 = new File("test.txt");
  Message<File> fileMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file1).build();
  ftpChannel.send(fileMessage);
  context.close();
```

In application.properiites file, I can setup a default host address but Here I need to pass the host address dynamically based on the user input. Could you please advice me on how to achieve that. It would be great If you suggest/provide some ideas.